# 1993 Toyota Pickup Odometer/Speedometer has stopped working

Tags: toyota

1993 Toyota Pickup Odometer/Speedometer has stopped working. I have a 1993 Toyota 4 cylinder 22R, manual 5 speed trans., no air, 2x4, and the speedometer and odometer have given up the ghost.  I would like to know how to fix it.  Is there just a loose cable? I have looked under the hood and can't make heads or tails of anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your vehicle is old enough to be a cable driven speedo affair. The set-up would be a gearbox drive gear, cable assembly, speedo head assembly. Any of these could fail/wear out and no longer operate the speedo/odometer internals. The first check is to disconnect the speedo cable at the speedo and see if it is rotating when the vehicle is driven. If it is rotating then the speedo head is suspect; if not the cable or drive gear is suspect.

Comment: Thanks Allan, where would I find the speedo cable and the speedo?

Comment: @RedCricket ... the "speedo" is the speedometer which is located in your dash. The speedo cable is attached to the rear of it, usually in the center.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks for the clarification.  I am afraid that removing the dashboard to get at speedo is beyond my skill level.